# Adding multiple BigInteger values to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to add multiple `BigInteger` values to an `ArrayList`. All I have found is examples that repeatedly add single values, each expressed on their own line of code. I'm looking for something like

```
ArrayList<BigInteger> array = {bigInt1, bigInt2, bigInt3};
```

and instead it's:

```
ArrayList<BigInteger> array = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
array.add(bigInt1);
array.add(bigInt2);
array.add(bigInt3);
```

Can it be done, without adding one element/line or using a for loop?

Comment: This is just the way to do it in Java. There are other language that support constructs that are less verbose. Actually, you don't even have to go that far: [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Looping) has them too.

Comment: why down vote? every one going to sock him . :(
in my opinion this is not good.

Comment: This is identical to another question that has a three didgit upvote value.....madness.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're after. You have four alternatives:

#### 1. Add items individually

Instantiate a concrete `List` type and then call `add()` for each item:

```
List<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
list.add(new BigInteger("12345"));
list.add(new BigInteger("23456"));
```

#### 2. Subclass a concrete `List` type (double brace initialization)

Some might suggest double brace initialization like this:

```
List<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<BigInteger>() {{
  add(new BigInteger("12345"));
  add(new BigInteger("23456"));
}};
```

I recommend not doing this. What you're actually doing here is subclassing `ArrayList`, which (imho) is not a good idea. That sort of thing can break `Comparator`s, `equals()` methods and so on.

#### 3. Using `Arrays.asList()`

Another approach:

```
List<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<BigInteger>(Arrays.asList(
  new BigInteger("12345"),
  new BigInteger("23456")
));
```

or, if you don't need an `ArrayList`, simply as:

```
List<BigInteger> list = Arrays.asList(
  new BigInteger("12345"),
  new BigInteger("23456")
);
```

I prefer one of the above two methods.

#### 4. `Collection` literals (Java 7+)

Assuming [Collection literals](http://code.joejag.com/2009/new-language-features-in-java-7/) go ahead in Java 7, you will be able to do this:

```
List<BigInteger> list = [new BigInteger("12345"), new BigInteger("23456")];
```

As it currently stands, I don't believe this feature has been confirmed yet.

That's it. Those are your choices. Pick one.

Comment: @Die He added wrapping to make it easier to read; both of those are technically one-liners. The latter is `List<BigInteger> list = Arrays.asList(new BigInteger("12345"), new BigInteger("23456"));`

Comment: Wow, those collection literals would be useful so people wouldn't be doing double-brace initialization so much. But it's still not available, not even in JDK-8.

Answer (score 6):

```
BigIntegerArrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Where BigIntegerArrays is a custom class which does what you need it to do. This helps if you are doing this often. No rocket science here - ArrayList BigIntegerArrays.asList(Integer... args) will use a FOR loop.

Comment: This is better than my solution :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Arrays.asList(new BigInteger("1"), new BigInteger("2"), new BigInteger("3"), new BigInteger("4"));
```

You could probably make a method that returns a new BigInteger given a String, called something like bi(..) to reduce the size of this line.

Answer (score 1):

If using a third party library is an option, then I suggest using [`Lists.newArrayList(E... elements)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList%28E...%29) from Google's [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
List<BigInteger> of = Lists.newArrayList(bigInt1, bigInt2, bigInt3);
```

And if mutability isn't required, then use an overload of [`ImmutableList.of()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#of()):

```
final List<BigInteger> of = ImmutableList.of(bigInt1, bigInt2, bigInt3);
```

This is IMO a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily accomplished with a helper function or two:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<BigInteger> array = newBigIntList(
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
            0xF,
            "1039842034890394",
            6L,
            new BigInteger("ffff", 16)
        );

        // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15, 1039842034890394, 6, 65535]
        System.out.println(array);
    }

    public static void fillBigIntList(List<BigInteger> list, Object... numbers) {
        for (Object n : numbers) {
            if (n instanceof BigInteger) list.add((BigInteger)n);
            else if (n instanceof String) list.add(new BigInteger((String)n));
            else if (n instanceof Long || n instanceof Integer)
                list.add(BigInteger.valueOf(((Number)n).longValue()));
            else throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<BigInteger> newBigIntList(Object... numbers) {
        ArrayList<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<>(numbers.length);
        fillBigIntList(list, numbers);
        return list;
    }
}
```